# n.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement - Exception creating result java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: spring-boot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting while using snowflake integration with spring boot :

ERROR n.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement - Exception creating result
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.arrow.memory.RootAllocator

Could you please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure that the Arrow library is installed properly. https://arrow.apache.org/install/

If it doesn't help or you cannot install it in your environment, try to override defualt result format for JDBC.

Here is example code:

```java
Statement = connection.createStatement();
Statement.executeQuery("ALTER SESSION SET JDBC_QUERY_RESULT_FORMAT='JSON'");
```